# Discrete singular integrals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\{\phi(n)\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ be a sequence of complex numbers with the following properties:

1. $\phi(0)=0$ and $|\phi(n)|\leq \frac{C_1}{|n|}$ for all $n\neq 0$ and $C_1>0$ is independent of $n.$
2. $|\phi(n+1)-\phi(n)|\leq \frac{C_2}{n^2}$ for all $n\neq 0$ and $C_2>0$ is independent of $n.$
3. $\sum_{-N}^N\phi(n)$ converges as $N\to\infty.$

Consider
$$
K(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\phi(n)\chi_{\left[n-\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}(x),
$$ which exists as a function in $L_p(\mathbb R).$ Can anyone prove that
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to \infty}\int\limits_{\frac{1}{\epsilon}<|x|<\epsilon}K(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$ exists? Also is the following true?
$|K(x)-K(x-y)|\leq C_3\frac{|y|}{|x|^2}$ for $|x|>2|y|.$ We also have by http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm66/cm66211.pdf that $|K(x)|\leq C_4|x|^{-1}$ for $x\neq 0.$ That is $K$ is standard Calderon-Zygmund kernel.

Comment: There must be a problem with the formulation of the integral. It is $0$.

Comment: @Dieter. Then the limit exists automatically. However do you have a proof?  If s please share.

Comment: The problem is $\epsilon < |x| < \epsilon$, this has to be replaced by something else.

Comment: @Dieter. Corrected now.

Comment: Surely $\epsilon < |x| < 1/\epsilon$.

Comment: @ Dieter. Yes. Corrected again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}\newcommand{\ep}{\epsilon}$Let $a_n:=\phi(n)$. Then
\begin{equation}
    K(x)=\sum_{n\in\Z}a_n 1(n-1/2\le x<n+1/2). 
\end{equation}
So, $K(x)=a_0=0$ if $1/2\le x<1/2$. So, for $\ep\in(0,1/2)$,
\begin{equation}
    I_\ep:=\int_{1/\ep<|x|<\ep}K(x)\,dx=\int_{|x|<\ep}K(x)\,dx
    =\sum_{n\in\Z}a_n J_n,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    J_n:=\int dx\,1(-\ep\le x<\ep,n-1/2\le x<n+1/2). 
\end{equation}

Let now $N:=\lfloor\ep+1/2\rfloor$, so that $N-1/2\le\ep<N+1/2$. Then $J_n=1$ if $|n|\le N-1$ and $J_n=0$ if $|n|\ge N+1$. Also, $0\le J_n\le1$ for all $n\in\Z$. So,
\begin{equation}
    I_\ep
    =\sum_{|n|\le N-1}a_n +O(|a_N|+|a_{-N}|). 
\end{equation}
So, $I_\ep$ converges, since $N\to\infty$, $\sum_{|n|\le N-1}a_n$ converges, and $|a_N|+|a_{-N}|=O(1/N)\to0$.

This provides the positive answer to your question.

The answer to your second question is no, in general. Indeed, take $x=3/2$ and let $y\downarrow0$. Then $K(x)=a_2$ and, eventually (for all small enough $y>0$), $K(x-y)=a_1$ and $|x|>2|y|$. However, for any real $C_3$, the inequality
$|K(x)-K(x-y)|\le C_3\frac{|y|}{|x|^2}$ will eventually fail to hold if $a_2\ne a_1$. However, it is not hard to see that the answer to your second question will be yes under an additional restriction such as $|y|\ge1$. (I will add details to this later -- now have to do something else.)

Comment: Dear Iosif. Thank you very much for your reply. I was trying to read a paper http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm66/cm66211.pdf. here the authors have taken a discrete kernel $\phi$ and then say $K$ to be linear extension of $\Phi$. Then they said that it is easy to check that the new kernel has those properties. So am I not extending it correctly?

Comment: @Abeginnermathmatician : I have added more on this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please take your time.

Comment: @Ionis. I am not very sure. But if we define $K(x):=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_n\chi_{(n-1/2,n+1/2)}.$ Then perhaps it works. At least the problem which you mentioned at $3/2$ will no longer be a problem.

Comment: @Abeginnermathmatician : I have taken a look at the paper you are reading, especially (K1)--(K3). I believe what they meant by "the linear extension" is the linear interpolation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20linear%20interpolation%20is,set%20of%20known%20data%20points.) Then I think their conditions (K1)--(K3) will hold. However, if you have further questions about those conditions for $K$ defined as the linear interpolation, please post them separately.

Comment: @Abeginnermathmatician : The modification of $K(x)$ that you suggested in your latter comment will not help: now let $x$ and $x−y$ be close to each other and so that $x>3/2>x−y$.

Comment: Dear Ionis. I am feel very grateful for your help. Thanks a lot. I'll try it by myself first and if I could not do, I'll ask the authors.

Comment: Dear Ionis. I looked some of the papers by those authors. They seem to consider the function $K(x):=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_nR(x-n)$ where $R(x)=1-|x|$ for $|x|<1$ and $0$ otherwise. Do you think this will work?

Comment: @Ionis. Also it is okay if the conditions are satisfied almost everywhere.

Comment: Dear Ionis. One more comment. Since you have already showed that we have a problem at $x=3/2.$ In the same way $x=n-1/2$ is problematic except $n=0.$ Is the condition on $K$ then true except these points i.e. except when $x\neq n-1/2$?

Comment: @Abeginnermathmatician : (i) I think $(1-|x|)_+$ will work. For details, you may want to post a separate question about this. (ii) With the construction as in your current post, you cannot get it almost everywhere either -- you would need to make $x$ bounded away from $n-1/2$.

Comment: @Abeginnermathmatician : My first name is Iosif (pronounced like Yosef), which is similar to Joseph, Josef, Giuseppe, José, Yusef, etc.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the name. I'll edit it later in my earlier comments.

Comment: Dear Iosif. Please look at my new post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408901/extending-a-discrete-singular-kernel-to-a-calderon-zygmund-kernel. Thank you very much.